# Share +1's between google plus page and website

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

I have a website with a +1 button. Can I somehow link or connect this website to the google plus page representing the same website?

So that the existing +1's are also shown for the page, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Google+ Direct Connect](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/#connect) lets you associate a website with a Google+ page and have the +1's merge. As I understand it it might take a few days for the +1's to combine.

Comment: Google Direct Connect is obsolete and being discontinued for non-blogger users. I wish we could get Google plus to work... My question on this same subject has remained unanswered for months... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330337/google-plus-button-versus-pages-pluses

Comment: @DerekWBeck excuse me? When has Google said that Direct Connect is being discontinued?

Comment: Ah, my apologies: It was Google Friend Connect that they are discontinuing. (http://support.google.com/friendconnect/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2440229) Sorry, too many Google Connects...