# Google Plus button versus page's pluses

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

I have a Google Plus page for my website, which is at https://plus.google.com/111407386830313266899?prsrc=3

As of this moment, it has 8 pluses.

But, if you look at my website, which is tied to it, http://www.derekbeck.com/1775/ , the G+ button only renders the number 4.

Now, it seems the G+ button is tied to the G+ page. If I plus the button on my site, the number on the G+ page increases. Yet apparently the reverse is not true.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: Update: this still remains broken, despite all of the advice below. And we wonder why G+ is failing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to close off this question, from @abraham , buried in the comments above:

"The website shows 6 +1's and the G+ page shows 8 followers, combine those and you get the +14 you see on the G+ page. If you add a G+ badge to the website instead of a +1 button you will see +14 there as well. – abraham Sep 7 at 22:51"

Comment: @abraham later added: "You can find the different types and sizes of badges in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/ "

Answer (score 2):

On your website, http://www.derekbeck.com/1775/, the +1 button is targeting your Google+ page's URL, https://plus.google.com/111407386830313266899.

You should actually be targeting your homepage as shown on your page: http://www.1775thebook.com

This means your markup will change from

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="small" data-href="https://plus.google.com/111407386830313266899"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="small" data-href="http://www.1775thebook.com"></div>
```

Comment: But if people plus1 the G+ page itself, this will not be reflected on the website. Isn't that right?

Comment: Once your Google+ page and website are wired up, the +1's will consolidate between them so a +1 in either place will be reflected in both :)

Comment: Okay, I'll try this and report back. Will I lose the few +1's I already have?

Comment: If the URL changes dramatically, then yes, a new +1 count will be reported.

Comment: Hmm... does this take time to propagate? I've changed the data-href link on my test version of the website: http://bit.ly/JEfL84 and it shows 1 like. (By the way, to be safe, I changed my google plus page and my data-href to http://www.derekbeck.com/1775/ as the other, www.1775thebook.com, merely forwards to the former.) But of course the live version, at http://www.derekbeck.com/1775/ , remains at 4 likes, with the G+ page at 8 likes.

Comment: I should add: the Google docs suggest it should be linked to the page: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/   (And this is the same logic behind my facebook likes link)

Comment: Ok, should note that, probably due to my caching program running, my test site, noted above, only shows 0 likes/pluses.

Comment: The badge and the +1 button work a bit differently. The badge will need to target your page to work, but the +1 button must target the URL that you'd like +1'd. Also, it can indeed take some time to synchronize.

Comment: After several days, the test site at the link above is still showing zero. Something is still up for me I guess.

Comment: @DerekWBeck The website shows 6 +1's and the G+ page shows 8 followers, combine those and you get the +14 you see on the G+ page. If you add a G+ badge to the website instead of a +1 button you will see +14 there as well.

Comment: Thank you sir, I will toy with this. I will try to find the G+ badge too. If you propose this as an independent answer to my question above, after I get it working, I'll give you answer credit. Thanks!

Comment: @abraham and, is there no way to have a badge as a simple low-profile icon w/ counter, as the button presently appears on my site?

Comment: You can find the different types and sizes of badges in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/